# How to increment the fields in the format used for writing into a file?

Tags: python

The format command used in python as follows:

```
      with open('outputfile.txt','a') as f2:    
         f2.write("{0}\t {1}\t {2}\t {3}\t".format(job_num,runtime,avg,(min,max)))
```

suppose I have a while condition then the result obtained after that needs to be append to the next set of fields like {4}\t {5}\t----up to the condition fails

so if anyone can suggest a way to do this in python, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your write statement to the following:

```
cols = [job_num, runtime, avg, min, max]
f2.write('{}\n'.format('\t'.join(cols)))
```

If you want to write another column, simply add that list.

I should say it looks like you are writing out a tab delimited file, try using the `csv` module because it will handle quoting your values correctly.

```
import csv

with open('outputfile.txt', 'a') as f2:
   writer = csv.writer(f2, delimiter='\t')
   cols = [job_num, runtime, avg, min, max]
   if some_condition:
       writer.writerow(cols)
   else:
       writer.writerow(cols+[another, column, here])
```